# How to make a template variable global?

Tags: php, wordpress, global-variables

Inside a template part file there's a variable I'd like to be able to use in my page templates. Page templates are in the theme directory, and the template part file are in a sub-directory called template parts.

My template part file is called 'roster-get-annual-data.php', and the variable is the title of a custom post type.  How can I make this title variable available in my page template?

Inside my template file (roster-get-annual-data.php) - within a wp_query:

```
if ($rosterQuery->have_posts()) {
    while ($rosterQuery->have_posts()) {
        $rosterQuery->the_post();

        $post_title = $post->post_title;
        set_query_var('post_title', $post_title);

?>
        <h1><?php echo $post_title; ?></h1>
            
        <div class="teams-wrapper">
                <?php
                $teams = get_field('single_rosters');
                foreach ($teams as $post) {

                    // Setup this post for WP functions (variable must be named $post).
                    setup_postdata($post);

                    // set the individual roster's ID
                    $rosterId = $post->ID;

                    // get the Class Title
                    if (!empty(get_field('class', $rosterId)) && !empty(get_field('grad_year', $rosterId))) {
                        $classTitle = ucwords(get_field('class', $rosterId)) . ' - Class of ' . get_field('grad_year', $rosterId);
                    } else {
                        $classTitle = get_the_title();
                    }
                ?>
                    <h2><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $classTitle; ?></a></h2>
                    <?php
                    // create empty $players array
                    $players = array();
                    // loop through the players acf repeater
                    if (have_rows('players', $rosterId)) {
                    ?>
                        <?php
                        while (have_rows('players', $rosterId)) {
                            the_row();
                            // place players into an array
                            $players[] =  get_sub_field('name');
                        }
                        ?>
                    <?php
                    }
                    // display the PLAYERS NAMES
                    ?>
                    <p class="players"><?php echo implode(', ', $players); ?></p>
                <?php

                }
                // Reset the global post object so that the rest of the page works correctly.
                wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>
            </div>;
?>
```

And then in my page template:

```
$post_title = get_query_var('post_title');
get_template_part('template-parts/roster-get-annual', 'data');
```

I thought this would give me just the $post_title variable, but instead it outputs the entire template without the $post_title variable.

Answer (score 0):

It´s not 100% clear to me what you want to achieve. But if you want pass args to a template you can do it with the 3rd parameter:

```
get_template_part('template-part', 'name', array('customkey' => 'value') );
```

see doc:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/

Comment: All I want is to pass the $post_title variable from from my roster-get-annual-data.php template to my page-schedule.php template.

When I use the get_template_part, I get the whole template (where I only want the one variable).

I've added this to my roster template: "$args = array('customkey' => $post_title)", and this to my page template, "get_template_part('template-parts/roster-get-annual', 'data', array('customkey' => 'post_title'))."  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: get_template_part "includes" the template - like require() - passing variables this way is not possible. If you just want the title - why not get it with get_the_title($ID) where $ID is the ID of the page/post?